# nginx loadbalancing in uwsgi

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I am new to uwsgi and trying to understand how it works.

In uwsgi say i have two setups say

1)

```
uwsgi --socket /tmp/uwsgi.sock --socket 127.0.0.1:8000 --master --process 2 --workers 1
```

which is a single uwsgi process with 2 child processes each having three threads listening to port 8000

2)

```
uwsgi --socket /tmp/uwsgi.sock --socket 127.0.0.1:8000 --master --process 2 --workers 3
uwsgi --socket /tmp/uwsgi2.sock --socket 127.0.0.1:8001 --master --process 2 --workers 3
```

similarly 2 uwsgi processes listening to ports 8000 and 8001

doubt 1 : Can we configure the uwsgi process to run like (2) and having them configured in nginx ?

doubt 2 : when does nginx loadbalances the requests
 (a) if it has multiple uwsgi process listening to multiple ports 
 (b) if it has single uwsgi process with multiple child processes

Which is the better (a) or (b) or is this is not the right way to use nginx to loadbalance uwsgi processes, if not how ?

Comment: Why have you used --process and --worker in same command. They both mean the same. If both are provided then --worker will override --process.

Answer (score 2):

The first approach is a lot saner and avoids nginx to pass requests to a worker already busy.

You may find some blog posts or doc about the thundering herd problem, i suggest you to read this: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/articles/SerializingAccept.html

basically unless you are on very specific needs (and limits) the first approach is the way to go.